# Unable to install Qt4

Tags: package-management, dependencies, qt4

When I give

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

It gives this error

```
Read packet list ... Done
Deployment tree generation
Read status information ... Done
Some packages can not be installed. This may mean
That an impossible situation was required or, if it is
Using a deployed development that some packages required
They have not been created yet or have been removed from Incoming.
The following information can help you resolve the situation:

The following packages have unsatisfied dependencies:
 Libqt4-dev: Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqt4-designer (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              Depends on: libqt4-dev-bin (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4)
              Depends on: libqt4-help (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqt4-network (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqt4-qt3support (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqt4-script (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed              

It depends: libqt4-scripttools (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqt4-sql (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqt4-svg (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              Depends on: libqt4-test (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              Depends on: libqt4-xml (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              Depends on: libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqtcore4 (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              It depends: libqtgui4 (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              Depends on: qt4-linguist-tools (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4)
              Recommend: libqt4-opengl-dev (= 4: 4.8.5 git192-g085f851 dfsg-2ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommend: libqtwebkit-dev (> = 2.0 ~) but it is not going to be installed
And: Unable to fix problems, there are blocked damaged packages.
```

I run a VirtualBox image with a fresh Ubuntu installation, and everything works fine, so I suppose I messed up with my Host.

How can I solve the issue?
Output is in Italian, it means I have broken packages.
How can I identify them?
I tried to instal by source, but again it complains of missing Lgl.

Thanks

**EDIT1**
When I give the command suggested by Rohit

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core
```

it outputs

```
Read packet list ... Done
Deployment tree generation
Read status information ... Done
Some packages can not be installed. This may mean
That an impossible situation was required or, if it is
Using a deployed development that some packages required
They have not been created yet or have been removed from Incoming.
The following information can help you resolve the situation:

The following packages have unsatisfied dependencies:
 Libqt4-core: Depends on: libqt4-dbus (= 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               It depends: libqt4-network (= 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               Depends on: libqt4-script (= 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               It depends: libqt4-test (= 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               It depends: libqt4-xml (= 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
               It depends: libqtcore4 (= 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4) but version 4: 4.8.5 + git192-g085f851 + dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is going to be installed
And: Unable to fix problems, there are blocked damaged packages.
```

Comment: Ah! I just learnt italian :)

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: sorry but it seems not to work

Comment: Please don't post in your language again or else I will down vote your question! Now try `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Let's try these: `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt dist-update`

Comment: doesn't work again